# VSCode - Python - Interactive window finds the file but main python file can not

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Basically I was trying to format the .csv files I have and I was initially working on interactive window to check every step.

When I decided to run the following code in the actual .py file, which has no issue in the interactive window, it raised the following file error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bearingset/health_20_0.csv'`.

I think I can just save the files from the interactive window, but I wonder what is the problem I am overlooking that it does not run in the actual code. For information my .py file is in the same folder with a folder called "bearingset" and all the .csv files are in that subfolder

```
# %%
import pandas as pd

nameList = ["health_20_0.csv",
            "comb_20_0.csv",
            "inner_20_0.csv",
            "outer_20_0.csv",
            "health_30_2.csv",
            "comb_30_2.csv",
            "inner_30_2.csv",
            "outer_30_2.csv",
            "ball_30_2.csv"
            ]

for fileName in nameList:
  fullName = f'"bearingset/{fileName}"'
  df = pd.read_csv(fullName)

  df = df.iloc[11:]
  df = df[df.columns[0]].apply(lambda x: [float(item) for item in x.split("\t")[0:-1]])
  df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist())
  df.to_csv(fullName, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

I think it should be this: `fullName = f"bearingset/{fileName}"`.

But the Error you give out has no relationship to that, It seems like the `cwd` caused it.

The `cwd` in the `interactive` is different from which in the `python file`. You can get it through this code:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

**Solution:**

1. If you run it in the debug mode, you can set it in the launch.json file:   `"cwd": "the path to the folder"`
2. You can take advantage of the absolute path instead of the relative path.
3. You can change the `cwd` in the python file: `os.chdir('path of the folder')`

Comment: Thank you, when I tried to get relative path by right-clicking on VSC, I realised that I need to specify the current folder containing both the python file and the other folder in relative path as well. It worked that way but to prevent problems in future, I have moved onto absolute path instead, as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
fullName = f'"bearingset/{fileName}"'
```

to

```
fullName = "bearingset/" + fileName
```

Comment: I am geting the fullName as 'bearingset/health_20_0.csv' and the same error with both methods. I don't know environment settings of VSCode is alway confusing me..